# CCLabelTTF Automatic Height

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

In the following code I am trying to make the text to wrap into the next line by setting the Y parameter in "dimensions" to 0. However the text does not wrap. It does wrap however, if I set it to some other positive value, like '100' for example.

This behavior is documented all across the web. Here's one of the articles: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_does_CCLabelTTF_support_line_breaks_and_wrapping

```
CCLabelTTF *distrDescLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit."
                                                      dimensions:CGSizeMake(director.screenSize.width - 20, 0) 
                                                      hAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft 
                                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
                                                        fontName:@"Helvetica" 
                                                        fontSize:16.0f];
```

I am using XCode 4.3.3 and Kobold2D 2.0.1 and running the sample under both iOS simulator and as an OS X app. Under both cases the results are the same.

Can anybody verify that this is a bug?

Comment: `kCCTextAlignmentCenter` is better than `UITextAlignmentLeft` for a parameter `hAliginment:`.

Answer (score 0):

For automatic height of a CCLabelTTF label I used this simple routine:

```
while (label.contentSizeInPoints.height > targetHeight) {
    label.fontSize = label.fontSize-0.5;
}
```

Don't use this extensively as a CCLabelTTF label is fully re-calculated at each loop.

Hope it would help someone

Answer (score -1):

In cocos2d-iphone there's no automatic line-break support. The link points to cocos2d-x, I suppose they added their own solution.

In cocos2d-iphone you'd have to break up the string and then display multiple labels, one for each line.

Comment: But if do specify a height "dimensions:CGSizeMake(100, 100)" for example, line breaking does work. I guess it should be quite simple to implement automatic height here.

Comment: the cocos2d supports line break, but the v-dimension set to 0 does not work